# Merging two identical word document displaying wrong page number using aspose word

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

Using Aspose Implementation:**Aspose.Words** for Java
Aspose Implementation-Version: **13.5.0.0**

---

Below are the documents:

1. [Source.docx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jcTwAXLw8qKmNgPUxEKBOAC2DllBBNLd)
2. [A1.docx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TKGTwqbYvsn_4wUYhpx_q3ilQt_j9P6o)
3. [A2.docx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18f8-l4fzvlRqLdqcwcpIoiNli9eEjkc8)
4. [A3.docx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1URLue9oDUy_Nyhhba3KHq21OhXQaRw29)

Using below code to append the word documents:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<Document> documentsToBeMerged=new ArrayList<Document>();
            Document source=new Document("D:/Source.docx");
            Document identicalDoc1=new Document("D:/A1.docx");
            Document identicalDoc2=new Document("D:/A2.docx");
            Document identicalDoc3=new Document("D:/A3.docx");
            documentsToBeMerged.add(identicalDoc1);
            documentsToBeMerged.add(identicalDoc2);
            documentsToBeMerged.add(identicalDoc3);
            mergeDocumentsWithSourceDocumentHeaderFooter(source, documentsToBeMerged, "D:/output.docx");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static void mergeDocumentsWithSourceDocumentHeaderFooter(
            Document destinationDocument, List<Document> mergingdocument,
            String outputFileName) throws Exception {
        try {
            for (Document document : mergingdocument) {
                document.getFirstSection().getPageSetup()
                        .setSectionStart(SectionStart.NEW_PAGE);
                document.getFirstSection().getHeadersFooters()
                        .linkToPrevious(true);
                destinationDocument.appendDocument(document,
                        ImportFormatMode.KEEP_SOURCE_FORMATTING);
            }
            AsposeUtil.convertNumPageFieldsToPageRef(destinationDocument);
            destinationDocument.updatePageLayout();
            destinationDocument.save(outputFileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }


 public static void convertNumPageFieldsToPageRef(Document doc) throws Exception
    {
        final String BOOKMARK_PREFIX = "_SubDocumentEnd";
        final String NUM_PAGES_FIELD_NAME = "NUMPAGES";
        final String PAGE_REF_FIELD_NAME = "PAGEREF";
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
        int subDocumentCount = 0;
        for (Section section : doc.getSections())
        {
            if (section.getPageSetup().getRestartPageNumbering())
            {
                if (!section.equals(doc.getFirstSection()))
                {
                    Section prevSection = (Section)section.getPreviousSibling();
                    Node lastNode = prevSection.getBody().getLastChild();
                    builder.moveTo(lastNode);
                    builder.startBookmark(BOOKMARK_PREFIX + subDocumentCount);
                    builder.endBookmark(BOOKMARK_PREFIX + subDocumentCount);
                    subDocumentCount++;
                }
            }
            if (section.equals(doc.getLastSection()))
            {
                Node lastNode = doc.getLastSection().getBody().getLastChild();
                builder.moveTo(lastNode);
                builder.startBookmark(BOOKMARK_PREFIX + subDocumentCount);
                builder.endBookmark(BOOKMARK_PREFIX + subDocumentCount);
            }
            for (Node node : section.getChildNodes(NodeType.FIELD_START, true).toArray())
            {
                FieldStart fieldStart = (FieldStart)node;
                if (fieldStart.getFieldType() == FieldType.FIELD_NUM_PAGES)
                {
                    String fieldCode = getFieldCode(fieldStart);
                    String fieldSwitches = fieldCode.replace(NUM_PAGES_FIELD_NAME, "").trim();
                    Node previousNode = fieldStart.getPreviousSibling();
                    if (previousNode == null)
                        previousNode = fieldStart;
                    builder.moveTo(previousNode);
                    Field newField = builder.insertField(MessageFormat.format(" {0} {1}{2} {3} ", PAGE_REF_FIELD_NAME, BOOKMARK_PREFIX, subDocumentCount, fieldSwitches));
                    previousNode.getParentNode().insertBefore(previousNode, newField.getStart());
                    removeField(fieldStart);
                }
            }
        }
    }


        private static String getFieldCode(FieldStart fieldStart) throws Exception
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (Node node = fieldStart; node != null && node.getNodeType() != NodeType.FIELD_SEPARATOR &&
                    node.getNodeType() != NodeType.FIELD_END; node = node.nextPreOrder(node.getDocument()))
            {
                if (node.getNodeType() == NodeType.RUN)
                    builder.append(node.getText());
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }

        private static void removeField(FieldStart fieldStart) throws Exception
        {
            Node currentNode = fieldStart;
            boolean isRemoving = true;
            while (currentNode != null && isRemoving)
            {
                if (currentNode.getNodeType() == NodeType.FIELD_END)
                    isRemoving = false;
                Node nextNode = currentNode.nextPreOrder(currentNode.getDocument());
                currentNode.remove();
                currentNode = nextNode;
            }
}
```

Issue: Total page `output.docx` contains `12` and last page footer is showing page number as `12 of 11` which is wrong.

Note: Both the documents `Identical1.docx` and `Identical2.docx` are same and also contains same References.

Please suggest me any solution how to resolve the page number issue.

Comment: Please share your Word documents for testing. I will investigate the issue and provide you more information on it. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @TahirManzoor Added word documents link to the post.

Answer (score 0):

We have tested the scenario using latest version of Aspose.Words for Java 18.6 and have not found the shared issue. Please use [Aspose.Words for Java 18.6](https://artifact.aspose.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/repo/com/aspose/aspose-words/18.6). Please note that Aspose.Words mimics the behavior of MS Word. If you join these documents using MS Word, the final output document will have 9 pages.

Moreover, please share the code of AsposeUtil.convertNumPageFieldsToPageRef method for further testing.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Yes it contains **9**  pages ans last page it is displaying as **10** of **9** pages I updated the post and added `AsposeUtil.convertNumPageFieldsToPageRef` method.

Comment: We have not found the shared issue when we open the output DOCX in MS Word 2016. Moreover, please update your code according to latest API. E.g. please use Field.Remove method instead of removeField(fieldStart), use Field.GetFieldCode method instead of getFieldCode(fieldStart).

Comment: In your case, I suggest you please do not use convertNumPageFieldsToPageRef method. There is no need to replace NUMPAGES with PAGEREF.